# Datetime calculate library in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a lot of data retrived from server with the following format:

```
{id:1,name:"xx",type:1,updated:'2014-01-01 12:21'},
{id:1,name:"xx",type:2,updated:'2014-01-01 12:21'},
{id:1,name:"xx",type:3,updated:'2014-01-01 12:21'},
.................................
```

Now I have to make some statistics:

1 By month

Calculate months belongs to this year and the range(`start` and `end`) of each month.

Calculate how many items for different type for each month in the current year.

2 By week

Calculate days belongs to this week and the range(`start` and `end`) of each day.

Calculate how many items for different type for every day in the current week.

3 By hour

Calculate hours(24) belongs to today and the range(`start` and `end`) of each hour.

Calculate how many items for different type for each hour;

I wonder if there is any date-time library to make the calculate work easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various libs can do this, I recommend [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks,I found this:http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/.  Just what I need.